# How to stream video capture between devices like video chat in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios4, video-streaming, audiounit, nsstream

Hi i want to make an app which does video calling between iOS devices .I have studied about opentok and idoubs but i want to do it myself from starting. I searched a lot but could not find any solution . I tried to achieve that in a way i think how video chat works . Untill now i have done following things (by using a **streaming bonjour tutorial**):

1. Create avcapture session and got cmsamplebufferref data in

   ```
   - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
      fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{



   if( captureOutput == _captureOutput ){



   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);



   //Lock the image buffer//
   CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
   //Get information about the image//
   uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);


   size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
   size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
   size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);




   //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef//
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
   CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);

   //We release some components
   CGContextRelease(newContext);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);





   previewImage= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
   CGImageRelease(newImage);

   [uploadImageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:previewImage waitUntilDone:YES];




   //We unlock the  image buffer//
   CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

   [pool drain];






    [self sendMIxedData:@"video1"];





   }


   else if( captureOutput == _audioOutput){



       dataA= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
       CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer;
       CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &currentInputAudioBufferList, sizeof(currentInputAudioBufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);
         //CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, NULL, &bufferList, sizeof(bufferList), NULL, NULL, 0, &blockBuffer);




       for (int y = 0; y < currentInputAudioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; y++) {
           AudioBuffer audioBuffer = currentInputAudioBufferList.mBuffers[y];
           Float32 *frame = (Float32*)audioBuffer.mData;

           [dataA appendBytes:frame length:audioBuffer.mDataByteSize];




       }

     [self sendMIxedData:@"audio"];
     }
   ```
2. Now sendMixeddata method is writing these video/audio bytes to NSStream.

   ```
   NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleAndRotateImage:previewImage], 1.0);

     const uint8_t *message1 = (const uint8_t *)[@"video1" UTF8String];

    [_outStream write:message1 maxLength:strlen((char *)message1)];

    [_outStream write:(const uint8_t *)[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    const uint8_t *message1 = (const uint8_t *)[@"audio" UTF8String];

    [_outStream write:message1 maxLength:strlen((char *)message1)];


     [_outStream write:(const uint8_t *)[dataA bytes] maxLength:[dataA length]];
   ```
3. Now the bytes are recived in nsstream delegate method on recieving device

   - NOw the problem is i dont know if thais is the way video chat works
     or not
   - Also i have no success how to use the receiving bytes to be displayed
     as video .
   - I tried by sending "audio" and "video1" string with the bytes to know
     if its video or audio. I also tried without using additional string.
     The images are received and displayed correctly but the audio is so
     distorted .
   - Please tell me if this is the correct way to make a video chat app or
     not . If yes than what should i do to to make it usable .For example
     : Should i send audio/video data together rather than separately like
     my example .Here iam using simple bonjour tutorial but how will i
     achieve the same with a real server

   Please guide me proper direction as i am stuck here .

Thanks 
 **(Sorry for the formatting . I tried but was unable to format correctly)**

Answer (score 0):

Video streaming apps use video codecs like vp8 or h.264, which will beat your JPEG encoded frames.

You should be able to display you received NSData by doing...

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```